# Remove text between two regex special character delimiters

Tags: python

```
s = '^^^@ """@$ raw data &*823ohcneuj^^^ Important Information ^^^raw data^^^ Imp Info'
```

In it, I want to remove texts between the delimiters ^^^ and ^^^.

The output should be "Important Information Imp Info"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regular expressions:

```
import re
s = '^^^@ """@$ raw data &*823ohcneuj^^^ Important Information ^^^raw data^^^ Imp Info'
important = re.compile(r'\^\^\^.*?\^\^\^').sub('', s)
```

The key elements in this regular expression are:

1. escape the `^` charater since it has special meaning
2. use the ungreedy match of `.*?`

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same way, but didnot apply "\", so was not getting the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
def removeText(text):
     carrotCount = 0
     newText = ""
     for char in text: 
           if(char == '^'):
                 # Reset if we have exceeded 2 sets of carrots
                 if(carrotCount == 6):
                      carrotCount = 1
                 else:
                     carrotCount += 1
           # Check if we have reached the first '^^^'
           elif(carrotCount == 3):
                # Ignore everything between the carrots
                if(char != '^'):
                     continue;
                # Add the second set of carrots when we find them
                else:
                     carrotCount += 1
           # Check if we have reached the end of the second ^^^
           # If we have, we have the message
           elif(carrotCount == 6):
                newText += char
      return newText
```

This will print "Important Information Imp Info."